# WeakMap doesn't work as expected in Chrome console

Tags: javascript

According to MDN,  a `WeakMap` object

> does not create strong references to its keys, so values in any
> WeakMap become candidates for garbage collection as well — as long as
> they aren't strongly referred to elsewhere.

But when I try the code below in Chrome, WeakMap doesn't work as expected:

```js
const wm = new WeakMap()
function foo(){
  const key = {bar: 1};
  const value = {bar: 2};
  wm.set(key, value)
}
foo()
console.log(wm)
```

[image]

Why there's still object in the WeakMap ?

Comment: Garbage collection isn't executed immediately after the function call, it might take some time (even minutes) before the WeakMap is emptied.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a weakmap will only change when GC (garbage collection) is called.

When testing weakmaps in a webpage, the page has to have a reason to trigger the GC for the weakmap to perform its tasks.

Going on a fairly static site with minimal elements such as github will take a while before the GC is called.

Going to a page like youtube and jumping around the video's timeline will trigger the GC much faster as there will be a lot more memory management happening in the browser.